# Document class with table in the header

Tags: tables, header-footer, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to write a document class in which the header of the first page has a table. The header of the following pages should have another table.

Well, I solved this problem in the .tex file (user file). However, I would like to take this solution to a class file to avoid damages in the code by less experienced users.

Here is how I solved it in the .tex file.

```
    % Pagestyle for all pages but the first one
    \pagestyle{fancy}{
      \fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers
     \headsep=25pt   %25pt normal
     \textheight=23.2cm %609pt normal
     \footskip=40pt  %30pt normal
      \chead{\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{10.8cm}|c|c|}                          \hline
     \multirow{4}{*}{\parbox[c]{4em}{\includegraphics[width=1.6 cm, height=1.6 cm]{logo.png}}}
     & \multirow{4}{*}{\small\textbf{NIT-\@divisao-\@nonorma}} &  &\\
     & & \multirow{2}{*}{\vspace{4em}\small\textbf{REV. N$^o$}} &
     \multirow{2}{*}{\vspace{4em}\small\textbf{P\'AGINA}}\\
     & & \multirow{2}{*}{\small\textbf{\@nrevisao}} & 
     \multirow{2}{*}{\small\textbf{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}\\
     & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \lhead{}
    \rhead{}

    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
    %..................................................................

    % Pagestyle for the first page
    \fancypagestyle{fpage}{
      \fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers
    \headheight=2cm  %12pt normal
    \headsep=25pt   %25pt normal
    \fancyhead{}
      \fancyhead[CO]{\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8.5cm}|c|c|}
     \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\parbox[c]{4em}{\includegraphics[width=1.6 cm, height=1.6 cm]{logo.png}}}
     & \multirow{4}{*}{\parbox[c]{8cm}{\small\textbf{\@titulonit}}} &     \textbf{Norma N$^o$} &
    \textbf{REV.N$^o$} \\ 
     & & \small\textbf{NIT-\@divisao-\@nonorma} & \small\textbf{xx} \\    \cline{3-4}
     & & \small\textbf{APROVADA} & \small\textbf{P\'AGINA} \\
     & & \small\textbf{EM \@dataaprov} &     \small\textbf{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \fancyfoot{}
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint on how to make it work on a header. Can I use the same code with `\newcommand`?

Comment: `\pagestyle{fancy}` does *not* take an argument: your code for normal pages appears in a group and so it's forgotten. You shouldn't be setting `\headheight` and `\textheight` as part of a page style: `\headheight` should have the same value for all pages.

Comment: Can you post the whole solution of your .tex-manuscript?